# Bad Request for mobile only on wordpress site

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a custom wordpress plugin that works fine on my computer's browser, but 400s out on mobile.  I am at a loss.

Here is the php for handling the request.

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_receive_api_call', 'recieveAPICall' );

function recieveAPICall() { 
    $dist = $_POST["distance"];
    if($dist > 50){
        $dist = 50; //distance should be limited for search
    }
    $zip = $_POST["zip"];
    $api_key_text = get_option('key_text');
    $api_url = 'http://some_url_i_am_using/endpoint?zip='.$zip.'&distance='.$dist;
    $response = wp_safe_remote_post($api_url, array(
        'headers' => array('X-API-Key' => $api_key_text)
    ));

    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        echo "ERROR";
    } else {
        $json_string = json_encode($response['body'], JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        echo $json_string;
    }
    die;
}

?>
```

Here is the javascript function I am using to make a post to the php which is called by clicking a button.

```
        var zip = $("#ffl_zip").val();
        var dist = $("#ffl_distance").val();
        if(dist == undefined || dist == null){
            dist = 25;
        }
        if(dist >= 50){
            dist = 50;
            $("#ffl_distance").val(50);
        }
        if(zip == undefined || zip == null || zip == ""){
            alert("Please enter a zip code to search.");
            return;
        }
        var data = {"action":"receive_api_call", "zip":zip, "distance":dist, enctype: "multipart/form-data"};
        
        $.post(ajaxurl, data).done(function(response) {
            if(response.includes("INVALID API KEY")){
                //FFLs = {};
            }
            //console.log(response);
            var json = JSON.parse(response);
            json = JSON.parse(json);
            //console.log(json);
            FFLs.list = json;
            FFLs.dict = {};
            $.each(json, function(key,value) {
                FFLs.dict[value.ffl] = value;
            }); 
            $("#ffl_select").empty();
            for(var i = 0; i < FFLs.list.length; i++){
                var ffl = FFLs.list[i];
                $("#ffl_select").append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value", ffl.ffl)
                    .text(ffl.licensee + (ffl.dba==""?"":" ("+ffl.dba+")") + ": " + ffl.premiseAddress + ", " + ffl.premiseCity + ", " + ffl.premiseState + ", " + ffl.premiseZip));
                if($("#ffl_select option[value=\"xxxxxxxx\"]").length > 0){
                    $("#ffl_select").val("xxxxxxxx").change();
                } else {
                    $("#ffl_select").change();
                }
            }
        }).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status + " " + error);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        });
```

Like I said, this all works fine on the computer, but no luck on mobile.  The alerts above spit out Bad Request, and 0 from the php.  Any clues?

Comment: Maybe because you are logged in in the backend on the computer? Try adding a hook for 'nopriv' too.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_nopriv_action/

Comment: Which specific 4xx error are you getting?

Comment: @klaassiek Looks like your are right. I logged in and it worked.  If you want to add that as an answer, I'll mark it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @ChrisHaas It was a 400.  Klaassiek pointed out correctly that I was probably testing not logged in on mobile.  I added the wp_ajax_nopriv_receive_api_call hook to my php code and it works now.